# How can I check that a string does not include the text of another string?

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript code:

```
if (fromState.name == "home.subjects.subject.exams.exam.tests.test" &&
    toState.name == "home.subjects.subject.exams.exam.tests") {
       tes.test.current = false; 
       tes.test = null;               
}
```

I understand that I can do a simple match here:

```
toState.name == "home.subjects.subject.exams.exam.tests"
```

To check the toState name.

But how could I check the toState.name does **not** include the string:

```
"home.subjects.subject.exams.exam.tests" ?
```

for example the toStateName could be:

```
"home" or "home.access" or "home.city"
```

Comment: will `indexOf` help ?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

ES6 version of this is (check out answer from Allison):

```
!str1.includes(str2)
```

The original accepted answer was:

You are looking for [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

```
var x = "home.subjects.subject.exams.exam.tests";
console.log(x.indexOf('subjects'));     // Prints 5
console.log(x.indexOf('state'));        // Prints -1
```

Comment: ES6 had been out for a year at the time this question was asked, and at the time this question was edited to reference my answer it had been out for 6 years. Nobody should be using indexOf to solve this problem.

Answer (score 40):

You could use `includes` and negate it.

`!str1.includes(str2)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: This is the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
var include_flag = toState.name.includes("home.subjects.subject.exams.exam.tests");
return !include_flag;
```

Using the JS includes method would probably be your best bet. I get I'm a little late in answering this question, but I was just googling this myself and came up with this answer after some fiddling with the code. This code will return true if `toState.name` does **NOT** include the string given.

Hope this helps anyone searching the same question I had!

Answer (score 0):

> But how could I check the toState.name does not include the string:

```
var strArr = "home.subjects.subject.exams.exam.tests.test".split(".");
var name = "home.subjects.subject.exams.exam.tests";
var contains = false;

strArr.reduce( function(prev, current){

   if ( name.indexOf( current ) != -1 )
   {
      contains = true;
   } 

   return prev + "." + current;

} );

if (contains)
{
   alert( "yes it contains" );
}
else
{
   alert( "Nope" );
}
```

Comment: Have you actually tested it? `var toState.name == "home.subjects.subject.exams.exam.tests";` incorrect, also `reduce` won't be called if there is only 1 element in array, `"home".split(".")` is 1 elem array

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly replaced `==` with `=`, and yes, rest of code works

Answer (score -1):

The original question contained a "?" ternary operator, so here is how to do it using a ternary operator.

Suppose you're writing a poker game and have a rainbow flop. Now suppose you want the missing suit from the flop.

```
let flop = "3h Js 9c";
let missingSuit = !flop.includes("c") ? "c" : 
                  !flop.includes("d") ? "d" : 
                  !flop.includes("h") ? "h" : "s";
// missingSuit equals "d"
```

Comment: I think you may be mistaking what looks like accidental punctuation included in the second to last code block for the beginning piece of a ternary operator. Nesting ternary operators in this way is difficult to read and generally frowned upon pretty unilaterally. If you’re going to do something like this (which I don’t recommend), you can make it more readable by encapsulating nested statements in parentheses and increasing the indentation for each new level of nesting.

Comment: Additionally, I’d recommend modeling cards with object-oriented programming (OOP) and not as strings. E.g., each card is an object with suit and value attributes, a card might belong to a deck, etc. Then you simply map over the dealt cards, access the suit attribute for each card, and find the missing suit via something like set difference.

Answer (score -1):

For me jQuery Version is 1.10.2

To check the substring within the string you can use **includes** jQuery function like this

```
var sub_str = "find"
var main_str = "find me if you can"
result = main_str.includes(sub_str)
if result{
  * Stuff todo if result found
}else{
  * Stuff todo if result not found
}

result true; // if you have sub string finder method separately and calling it from somewhere else.
```